# Check if Symfony Profiler is enabled in own bundle

Tags: php, symfony, toolbar, profiler

I implemented a own data collector and service decorators to add profiling information about my bundle to the Symfony Profiler.

Now I want them to only be enabled if symfony has the profiler enabled.

I already put all debug service definitions in its own service.yaml to only load it in my bundle extension if a specific condition is met.

```php
$yamlLoader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));

$yamlLoader->load('services.yaml');

if(<condition>) {
  $yamlLoader->load('debug_services.yaml');
}
```

Is this the correct way to implement this and if yes, which is the safest  to match againt to check if the profiler is available and enabled?

Comment: As far as the condition goes, take a look at DoctrineMigrationsExtension::getBundlePath which uses the kernel.bundles_metedata parameter to see if a bundle is registered.  The doctrine bundle has a compiler pass which checks to see if the profile service is defined and if not, they remove their profile related services.  That might be cleaner for you if you only have a couple of decorated services.  Your above approach looks like it will work but you might also poke around a bit in some of the other bundles as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SERVER`

```
$yamlLoader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        
$yamlLoader->load('services.yaml');
        
if($_SERVER['APP_ENV'] === 'dev' || (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
  $yamlLoader->load('debug_services.yaml');
}
```

Comment: While it probably works as intended, being in `dev` !== having the profiler enabled

Comment: Not to pile on but if you were going to key off of the current environment then Symfony provides better ways of doing so than using super globals.